# CMonthCalCtrl coloring specific days

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to color **specific** days using the CMonthCalCtrl control from the MFC. I think it's impossible, if so, there is a trick to simulate something like that?.

Pay attention to *specific days*, I don't want to color all the days. Because to do that, I got the method SetColor.

Comment: What have you tried? Please read the following: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot **color** individual days, only **bold** them.  You use the [`CMonthCalCtrl::SetDayState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d45w8z1w.aspx) method for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you, I know it. So, I did my own calendar control.